# Making A Cat World: How would a cat carry supplies on their person?

Tags: society, technology, tools

This is the first in what I plan to be a series of questions on how cats with a human level intelligence would be able to work things out.

I was inspired by an artist called [Neytirix](https://www.deviantart.com/neytirix) and the [world](https://www.deviantart.com/neytirix/art/Passing-through-834355010) she drew for her cat, so I decided that I want to make a world of my own for my cats. In her drawings the cats carry tools, weapons, and storage much like a human or their pack animal would. I think the cats in my world would also use these items, but it would make more sense if the cats had tools and weapons tailored to their bodies and not as if a human put them on a cat. Nothing about their anatomy will be different then a normal domestic cat, but they will have human level intelligence.

I plan to ask more questions to get some ideas of how there tools and weapons could look, but for now I'll start with how they could carry supplies on them. They should be able to put on whatever they would use without necessarily having help.

If anything needs to be clarified please tell me and I will make changes as needed. Thanks!

Comment: if their anatomy is the same as a domestic cat how are they holding tools?

Comment: Without anatomical changes, the answer is simple: cats can carry one item, in their mouth.

Comment: Do note that without opposing thumbs, cats have a big problem using most tools.

Comment: Which all ^ leads to a more fundamental question (if one that's not directly relevant to the question as it stands), how do they acquire or create these tools in the first place?

Comment: If there are no anatomical changes? The the answer is obvious. They get their human slaves to do all the carrying for them.

Comment: Prehensile tails wouldn't be a big change, and it would help them reach their backs... I think it would be really useful for tool using cats.

Comment: @John my thoughts where that the cats would probably hold them in their mouth.

Comment: @Pelinore I agree with you and I'm planning to ask questions relating to that another time.

Answer (score 5):

With no changes in their anatomy, cats can mostly use their mouth to handles something: either by holding and lifting it, if not to big, or by pulling it on the ground.

In other words, the first way would resemble how they carry their kittens or small preys like mice and birds. The second way would resemble how they move bigger catches, like rabbits.

The remaining way is by means of their paws, like they do when they are playing with something, kicking it around, or trying to open a door, by pushing it to the side.

Answer (score 2):

While cats are certainly individuals. as a general observation from having owned five cats as pets, they don’t like wearing things, especially tight things.

Harnesses can restrict a cat's movement, they can get their claws caught in them and the experience of putting them on can cause them distress.

I imagine cats might carry handbags that they can quickly drop or leave for later return in case their whims at any given moment carry them elsewhere from needing the bag or its contents at that given point in time.

Answer (score 2):

With human level intellegince then the answer is they get another animal to do the heavy moving. So you just need your cats to train horses for the heavy goods. Maybe they would also train something like a small dog for day-to-day carrying of small items.

Answer (score 1):

**One thing at a time.**

[image: cat carries socks]

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TUA03xCO2eo

This cat carries a sock.  So too most cats in your world: a sock.  Some of them might sometimes carry a pipe cleaner, or a raw piece of sphagetti, or Barbie's pants.  Occasionally the most boss cats carry dead chipmunks and they will assert they killed the chipmunks even though the chipmunks are usually dried up and sometimes flattened by cars.  Best not to argue.

But cats carry only one thing at a time, because they are cats, and they only have one mouth.